# Select ONLY the very next select box (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the value of *only* the very next select box after the current field.

The form is a long list of rows with fields that have the same classes. On focus of the "quantity" field in "row 1" I want to change the "type" select box to "boxes" in that same row. All the code I try makes ALL of the "type" select boxes on the entire page change. I only want the most immediate one, closest to the quantity field to change.

**The UOM field is the field I am attempting to change when the user focuses on Quantity.**

Thanks!

```
<tr class="draggable odd">
<td class="content-multigroup-cell-field-part-num">
    <div id="edit-group-order-0-field-part-num-value-wrapper" class="form-item">
        <label for="edit-group-order-0-field-part-num-value">J&amp;B No.: 
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-text text idleField" value="" size="10" id="edit-group-order-0-field-part-num-value" name="group_order[0][field_part_num][value]" pattern="[0-9]*">
    </div>
</td>
<td class="content-multigroup-cell-field-quantity">
    <div id="edit-group-order-0-field-quantity-value-wrapper" class="form-item">
        <label for="edit-group-order-0-field-quantity-value">Quantity: 
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-text text idleField" value="" size="5" id="edit-group-order-0-field-quantity-value" name="group_order[0][field_quantity][value]" pattern="[0-9]*">
    </div>
</td>
<td class="content-multigroup-cell-field-quantity-type">
    <div id="edit-group-order-0-field-quantity-type-value-wrapper" class="form-item">
        <label for="edit-group-order-0-field-quantity-type-value">UOM: 
        </label>
        <select id="edit-group-order-0-field-quantity-type-value" class="form-select" name="group_order[0][field_quantity_type][value]">
            <option selected="selected" value="">- None -
            </option>
            <option value="Box(es)">Box(es)
            </option>
            <option value="Case(s)">Case(s)
            </option>
            <option value="Each">Each
            </option>
            <option value="Feet">Feet
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

J&B No.: 
            
            
        
    
    
        
            Quantity: 
            
            
        
    
    
        
            UOM: 
            
            
                - None -
                
                Box(es)
                
                Case(s)
                
                Each
                
                Feet

Comment: Can you post the current code/markup you're using?

Comment: It would help to see the actual html to see the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the code. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using table markup and are inside a focus event of an element inside a td.

```
$('input.quantity').focus( function() {
    //get current cell, find nearest select.type in the following siblings
    $(this).parent()
           .nextAll()
           .find('select.type:first').val('boxes');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)?